# Why is my toilet bubbling & flushing when sinks are used?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, flus

I live in a trailer with 2 bathrooms. Lately the guest bathroom toilet has been bubbling and filling up and flushing any time any sinks, baths or the other toilet gets used.

Does any one know why this happens?

It only happens to the guest bathroom, not the master bathroom. Nothing else in the guest bathroom is affected only the toilet.

Comment: How in the World do People type and capitalize Random Words so frequently and how Come their Punctuation keys Dont seem To Work

Comment: Does the level of the water in the _tank_ remain constant, only the level in the _bowl_ changes, i.e. it is not _flushing_?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a partial blockage in your drainage pipes.  Most likely the drain line starts at your master bath, then goes past your guest bath on its way to the sewer.  So when you flush your master bath toilet, there's a lot of water that goes into your drain system all at once that can't get past the blockage very fast, and causes a backup into your guest bathroom toilet.  Probably need to have a plumber or handyman come out and snake your drain lines to clear the blockage.  Hopefully it's just a blockage that can be easily cleared and not a partially collapsed drain line.